# Samsung Galaxy Ace locks automatically when clock application is selected

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, lock-screens, samsung-galaxy-ace, clock

Got my Samsung Galaxy Ace a few days ago. Been working properly till yesterday when something strange started happening. Whenever I select the Clock application, the application starts, I see my clock for a brief moment (like a second) and then the phone locks. When I unlock it, it returns to Clock app and then immediately locks again! This keeps happening, not even giving me time to return to the home screen.

If I reboot the phone then it returns to the home screen and it works properly till I select the Clock application again. Then the same story happens and repeats.

So basically once I select the Clock application, the phone will lock. My phone OS is Android 2.3 Gingerbread. Can't figure why this happens. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you installed an app recently? The general consensus in troubleshooting is to check if you installed an app/widget from google play first, if not,   then the second question is, did you play with something that caused it without knowing/understanding about it?

Comment: sounds like it's crashing on start, does it go black screen and shows you an error dialog ?

Comment: Have you tried deleting data of the clock app? Enter settings then go to Applications then Manage Applications. From there you have to select the All tab and then find the clock app. There should be a Clear Data button. Just bear in mind that all your data and possibly alarms will be included.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and solved it by simply re-setting the "Screen timeout" option in display settings. It seems some app messed it up.